Western about blind man and his wife
There's an old Western about a blind man and his wife, who is one of the best marks-women around. The movie starts with her being woken up and she immediately has a gun in her hand.
At least 70s/80s/90s; I do not remember the cast at all I saw it around at least ten years ago; American Wild West movie; there was a scene in the movie where there's one of the old shooting competitions-first to take their gun out & shoot & kill-and it was the blind man vs another person, and they missed, but the blind man had only one bullet in his gun because the mayor or someone was trying to get him killed, so his son threw him a bullet & he used it

what era? 70s? Do you know anything about the cast?

Any more information that may help to identify it? When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Any additional details you might remember?

At least 70s/80s/90s; I do not remember the cast at all
I saw it around at least ten years ago; American Wild West movie; there was a scene in the movie where there's one of the old shooting competitions-first to take their gun out & shoot & kill-and it was the blind man vs another person, and they missed, but the blind man had only one bullet in his gun because the mayor or someone was trying to get him killed, so his son threw him a bullet & he used it

I don't think that it really fits. But some elements are similar to The Quick and the Dead.

Another imperfect fit, there are similarities to Blind Justice (www.imdb.com/title/tt0109294/).

I'm pretty sure it's The Quick and the Dead.  Here is the described scene.  
Some of the details described are mixed up, but it also matches with Sharon Stone waking up with a gun at some point.  I couldn't find a clip of that.
